# How to remap keys with different functions?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, accessibility

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) on Mac have this great feature, it can map a single key with two different featuers, I'm wondering if I can do this on ubuntu.

The feature is that it can map enter to control, and when you "click" enter, it will send enter, but when you hold enter, it will send control. Also you can set a timeout if you want, then enter will only be control during the timeout. After that you'll get enter.

Same thing can do on other keys, I can map right command as enter when it is only pressed once, but it is still command if I hold it.

Is there any software which can do this in ubuntu? or better if there is a generic linux solution.

[image]